# how to use IN clause in visual c# 2010 dataset?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, dataset

i have made a dataset and need to use **IN** clause like the below example

here is my query:

```
select field1,field2 from tablename where id **IN** (@ids)
```

the number of id parameter is not fixed and changes every time for the above query

now i want to use it in dataset.

i don't know how to use it

i need to use IN in Visual Studio 2010 Dataset Environment.

i want to know how can i replace @ids with 1,2,3,4,...?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `LINQ to DataTable`:

```
var list = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var result = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                      .Where(row => list.Contains(row.Field<int>("Id"));
```

Comment: this is not good for me. i need to make the query do this
i have 10 millions and more of records on database, and i don't need all of them to be fetched.

Comment: @AliAhmadi: so you need to update your question for more clear.

Comment: i declare a split function and pass it as a string and solved

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
     public DataSet GetDataSet(string ConnectionString, string SQL)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "YOU SQL QUERY WITH WHERHE";
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    conn.Open();
    da.Fill(ds);
    conn.Close();

    return ds;
}
```